# How to detect if a sensor is disconnected?

Tags: pcb, sensor

I am currently working on a PCB design. I want to find a way to detect if sensor is not plugged in properly or malfunctioning. For this I want to know how to detect if my load is 0A but I don't know how to do it. I'm not even sure it's the best way to deal with this problem.
The sensor would be this one https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/capteurs-de-pression/1115924 and it consumes 3.5mA

Comment: What current is normally taken by the sensor?

Comment: What is the sensor? How is it connected?

Comment: A schematic will really help here. Without knowing the sensor, or your measuring method, there is no way to answer this reliably

Comment: What's the sensor? How is it being driven? How is it being read? All of these questions will impact how you can do what you're asking.

Comment: Measure the 3.5 mA consumption via a shunt resistor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust honeywell to make a good sensor with this already accounted for:

[image: datasheet electrical specs]

You can see that the sensor range is from 0.5V to 4.5V, and they provide a graph as well:

[image: datasheet output graph]

So you know that voltages greater than 4.5V or less than 0.5V indicate failed ground or power lines respectively. To catch an open sensor line fault you may add a small pull down resistor to the line close to the ADC.

All snips captured from the manufacturers datasheet hosted here: https://docs.rs-online.com/3359/0900766b814d9e04.pdf

Comment: Thank you this is a much better way to see the problem. Just by curiosity is there a way to compare currents as the op-amp does for voltage?

Comment: @ThomasPerr I would use a low side current sense resistor and an opamp, but I feel like there's better ways. Current feedback opamps exists however I know nothing about them (blew up the ones I had back in the 90's, never looked back). I suspect the true analog wizards here could throw together a neat circuit out of transistors that accomplishes "current comparison" natively - it could be a good question to ask.

Comment: @ThomasPerr allright I did a quick google and this researchgate paper for a NEW AND IMPROVED current comparitor cites establishes current comparitors for reference: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Conventional-CMOS-current-comparators-a-Traffs-and-b-Tangs_fig1_226277093 . The Traff's configuration looks simple and easy to simulate, perhaps give it a go?

Comment: it looks really interesting and pretty simple, thank you very much for your time